# Problem mounting partition after Gparted

Tags: data-recovery, gparted, partitioning

I had 3 partitions on my hard drive and I tried  to merge `sda5` with `sda6` but for some reason `gparted` crashed. Now when I try to mount `sda5`, all I find in it is `lost+found`.
I’m running Lubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Comment: i don't want to recover the data i wan't how to fix the partition s i cant mount it again

Comment: If you're not interested in recovering the data on your partitions, just delete them and then remount them!  **Warning this will delete all of your data!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash during a partition merge likely damaged the file system. That's why you should create backups beforehand.

- The easiest “fix” is to re-format the partition, if you don't care about any data that may be recoverable.
- If you're lucky, you can salvage most of the data with `fsck`, but you should [create a raw copy](/a/589060) of `/dev/sda5` and work on the image, in case `fsck` makes things worse.

  You can run `fsck /path/to/image` directly on the image file, but if you want to access the (hopefully) recovered files, you need to mount it with the `loop` option:

  ```
  sudo mount -r -o loop /path/to/image /path/to/mountpoint
  ```

  This mounts the image *read-only*, since you only want to look at and salvage its data and not modify it (accidentally).
- Lastly, if `fsck` doesn't help, you can try more low-level [data recovery](/q/41601) (assuming the partition contained an ext4 file system). You can use the (unaltered) disk image again, that you may have created earlier, in case you re-purposed the disk space for something else in the mean time.

In any case you should re-format the partition in the end. Don't keep using an obviously broken file system, even if you can fix it enough to salvage your data.

Comment: See my update to the answer.